# How to identify a system query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently getting the details of executed queries from the table sys.dm_exec_query_stats. Is there any way to identify whether an executed query is a system query or not, using some information in sys.dm_exec_query_stats table or using some other methods

Comment: You have to define what is a `system query` because the same query that uses `sys.tables` (for example) can be sent from a user connections or from a system connection. Regarding connections / sessions there is following flag (`is_user_process`) within `sys.dm_exec_sessions` view..

Answer (score 2):

In `sys.dm_exec_sessions` there is a column named `is_user_process`. `0` means system process, `1` is user process. MSDN link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx).

To show connection to your tables I post query that I am using for monitoring activity:

```
SELECT distinct 
        s.session_id,
        s.login_name,
        c.client_net_address,
        w.wait_duration_ms,
        w.wait_duration_ms/1000/60 as [min],
        w.wait_type,
        w.resource_address,
        w.blocking_session_id,
        w.resource_description,
        CAST (st.text as nvarchar(max)) AS [SQL Text],
        s.is_user_process
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions S
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON S.session_id = c.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs on c.most_recent_sql_handle = qs.sql_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS w ON w.session_id = s.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
ORDER BY s.is_user_process DESC, w.wait_duration_ms DESC
```

Comment: This refers to the context of process right? Actually I need the information on a query basis. That is out of all queries executed in the system I need to filter which ones are system queries. If I am right, only system stored procedures will come in this category(ie system query)

Comment: Yes, process, sessions etc. So if I launch some script that use for example `sp_send_dbmail` - it will be system query? If not, please, give an example of what you mean by **system query**.

Comment: As per my understanding, processes with spid < 50 are system processes. By system query I mean those queries initaiated from system processes

Comment: spid < 50 is one of there attribute but you can not see what *query's* there are running (if they are running query's of course)